# Global event handler for AJAX POST requests in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to register an event handler for all POST requests done by jQuery.post(...).

I can install a global Handler for all ajax requests with:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(ev,xhr) {
  console.log(xhr);
});
```

But I want to have the handler called only for POST requests. But I can't figure it out:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(ev,xhr) {
  if(xhr.__IS_POST_OR_WHATEVER()) {
     console.log(xhr);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one additional argument passed to the `ajaxComplete` event handler; an object which contains the settings the request was made with. This object has a `type` property which is what you need to check:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(ev, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.type === 'POST') {
    console.log('Do something');
  }
});
```

More info available in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/#ajaxComplete-handler).